# Change single column / row background color in Flutter DataTable

Tags: flutter

I have a table showing the monthly instalment amount of a property with different interest rate and years.  I would like to highlight a particular row and column based on user's selection.  The best I can do now is like this:

[image]

I have a few questions here:

1. the background color does not fill out the whole cell, it seems the width is fixed to the header label width (with padding on both sides?)
2. how can I set background color of a particular header cell (not the whole header)
3. how can I make the header label center?

Here is my code:

```
  return DataTable(
    border: TableBorder.all(
      color: Colors.grey,
    ),
      columns: [
        for (var i=0; i < TableHeader.length; i++)  // a list of columns (5yrs, 10 yrs etc)
          DataColumn(
            label: Text(TableHeader[i]),
          ),
      ],
      rows: [
        for (var i = 0; i < Interests.length; i++)  // a list of interest rates (2, 2.25, 2.5 etc)
          ShowRecord(Interests[i]),
      ]
  );


DataRow ShowRecord(_rate){
  TableRecord = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Years.length; i++){
    TableRecord.add(CalInstal(_rate, Years[i]));
  }
   return DataRow(
     cells: [
       DataCell(
         SizedBox.expand(
           child: Container(
             padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
             color: Colors.red,
              child: Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text(_rate.toString())),
           ),
           ),
       ),
       DataCell(Text(TableRecord[0].toString())),
       DataCell(Text(TableRecord[1].toString())),
       DataCell(Text(TableRecord[2].toString())),
       DataCell(Text(TableRecord[3].toString())),
       DataCell(Text(TableRecord[4].toString())),
       DataCell(Text(TableRecord[5].toString())),
       if (Years.length > 6)
        DataCell(Text(TableRecord[6].toString())),
     ]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To color entire rows, just add the `color` property to your `DataRow` widget like this:

```dart
return DataRow(
        color: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
        cells: [
        ...
```

For columns, what you have seems to work. Try changing the `columnSpacing` property of your `DataTable` to remove the white padding.

```
return DataTable(
    columnSpacing: 0.0,
    border: TableBorder.all(
      color: Colors.grey,
    ),
      columns: [
      ...
```

For heading background color. Add the `headingRowColor` property to your `DataTable` similar to how I added the `color` property to `DataRow`.

To center your heading labels, simply wrap your `Text` widgets with `Center` widgets.